# How to build kernel module for Cortex A8?

Tags: arm, beagleboneblack, cortex-a8

I want to compile this code which enables cycles counters on ARM Cortex A8 through Debian OS on target. I wrote this code in `/home` and want to compile it.

> How can i compile it and where should i put the output file?

- i am just a beginner in embedded systems,
- i tried to follow some links but all failed
- i don't actually know the steps to do that because i am not familiar with Linux

**Code:**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

static int OldState;

int __init init_module(void)
{

  /* enable user-mode access */
  asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 0\n\t" :: "r"(1));

  /* disable counter overflow interrupts (just in case)*/
  asm ("MCR p15, 0, %0, C9, C14, 2\n\t" :: "r"(0x8000000f));

  printk(KERN_INFO "user-mode access to performance registers enabled\n");

  return 0;
}


void cleanup_module(void)
{
}
```

Comment: Question is too broad for SO. Look for tutorials about Linux Module development, raspberry pi etc. There must be plenty.

Answer (score 1):

You need ARM toolchain (cross-compiler) for this. It will compile sources for ARM architecture on your x86 machine. See [this](http://elinux.org/Toolchains#CodeSourcery) and [this](http://elinux.org/ARMCompilers).

Once you installed ARM toolchain, provide `CROSS_COMPILE` environment variable to `make` (or just do something like `export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-eabi-` in your shell before running `make`). Kernel build system will use this variable as prefix for tools like `gcc`, `as`, `ld` etc. This way your module will be built for ARM architecture. Use `file` tool on your module file (`.ko`) to be sure it was built for ARM.